# How do I get my background image to not be cut off at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have a large background image that is fixed with text being displayed on top of it, however the bottom of the image is being clipped off. I want the image to be displayed completely and not be cropped off.

```
 #content {
            background-image: url(../images/bean.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            height: 40em;
            margin-top: 0;
            padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: display:inline-block; could help

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: 100% 100%;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set background-size to be 100vw 100vh i.e `background-size: 100vw 100vh;`

```
#content {
            background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1400/1400/sports/3/);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100vw 100vh;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            height: 40em;
            margin-top: 0;
            padding: 0;}
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/buqaju/1/

Comment: Won't this stretch the image when you resize the browser?

Comment: Only it will not keep the proportional between width and height. However, all the image will be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

To have the background always cover the whole container you can use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/
Pay attention to browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size (hint: No IE8)

Also, I noticed it's not very performant on pages with a lot of transparencies and moving backgrounds, but other than that I use it quite a lot and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height?

`height: 100em;`

Comment: I forgot to add that I have a fixed footer at the bottom of the page, so if I increase the height, the footer moves down which I don't want

Comment: Then adjust the background size:

    background-size: 40em;

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
background-size:100%;
```

use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: amazing how ppl down vote without explaining why. If you use background-size:cover; if the size of the image you are using is not close to the size of the div, the image will cover the background but the position of the image may not be exact. If you use background-size:100%; same issue applies except you may face the problem the OP is having. If you use background-size:100% 100%; it compresses or expands the image to fit the exact size of your div without any cutoffs or offset positions. Maybe we should explain before we down vote, especially when the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg_care{
        background-image: url(../img/care-area.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
}
```

just use background-size as cover it wont cut off.

Answer (score 0):

You could also modify your background as such:

```
  background: url(xyz.jpg) no-repeat **center center** fixed;
```

where you change the **center** values as needed (left,right,bottom,top). Depending on the image it may be useful.